# How can i get the value of the item in IEnumerable with member in another class?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

`enter code here`I have GlobalTerms class that contains a data member terms which is a list of type Term.

Each Term class has 3 members.

1. int Id;
2. bool IsApproved;
3. string Note;

so, it looks like:

```
Class GlobalTerms
{
  IEnumerable<TermInfo> UserTerms;

}

Class TermInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note{ get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved{ get; set; }
}
```

If I have an GlobalTerms object (globalTerms), how can I get a TermInfo object where the Status in TermInfo equals True?

I tried to write something like this:

```
     GlobalTerms globalTerms = new GlobalTerms();
                globalTerms.UserTerms.Where(x => x.IsApproved.Equals(true))
                    .Select(x => x.Id);
```

My task was checking that all items in UserTerms has true in IsApproved field;
   In result I received error:
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
Thank you in advance for your help,

***ANSWER:***
In result, this issue was solved used the next code:

```
 *termsList* - is a IList<GlobalTerms> 

foreach (var singleTerm in termsList)
            {
                var sourceTermsList = singleTerm.UserTerms.ToList();
                foreach (var status in sourceTermsList)
                {
                    status.IsApproved.Should().BeTrue();
                }
            }
```

Thank Guys to everyone,

Comment: The NRE is because `GlobalTerms iTerms = new GlobalTerms();` and then `iTerms.UserTerms.Where....`, You haven't instantiated `UsersTerms` in your object, it is `Null` and when you try to use `Where` on it, you get exception. Once that is fixed you can modify your condition to `Where(x=> x.IsApproved)`

Comment: I would hope it is that simple but the above code would never do anything useful without that list being populated from some other source, so we might just be missing relevant code.

Comment: Habib, thanks a lot for your idea:) It's helps me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you created new object and its property UserTerms is null

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `UserTerms` member in `GlobalTerms`, so when you create a new instance of `GlobalTerms` the `UserTerms` `IEnumerable` is null. You need to set it to a non-null collection of some sort before you can run linq queries against it.

Also, what is the `IsApproved` member? If that's a nullable type that might be your issue.

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake,     isApproved is here:                                                                   Class TermInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note{ get; set; }
    public bool isApproved{ get; set; }
}